# Qlik Sense - Get list of user apps and get current logged in user

Tags: javascript, api, qliksense

I'm user the Qlik Sense Api's and I'm a little frustrated as the Qlik docs are very confusing.

So I have three things I'm needing to do.

1. Get the current logged in user.
2. Get a list of apps for that user.
3. Is there a page which clearly lists the methods available for the (qlik) arg passed in the function?

Thank you

```
require(['js/qlik'], function (qlik) {
        // I need to get the current logged in user from here 
        // and also a list of apps this user can view                   
});
```

Update:

```
// for getting the user this works like a charm
var global = qlik.getGlobal(config);
global.getAuthenticatedUser(function(reply){
    alert('User:'+reply.qReturn);
});
```

For getting the apps the following code has been suggested. I'm not sure how they are different.

```
// This one is what I have found from trying various code snippets found in the documentation.
// This seems to work but there are errors when displaying the apps with the below code snippet.
qlik.getGlobal(self.config).getAppList(function(list) {console.log(list);});

// suggested snippet gives the following errors.
qlik.getAppList(function(list) {console.log(list);});

Error: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/app/%3Ftransient%3D?reloadUri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response"

qlik.getGlobal(self.config).getAppList(function(list) {

ia.getList('sheet', function (reply) {

    $('#qlik-cont').append('<div id="div-' + key + '"></div>');

    var stop = setInterval(function(){

        ia.global.getProgress(ia.model.handle).then(function(progress)
        {
            console.log("DoReload progress", progress);
                });
            }, 100);

            ia.doReload().then(function(result){
                if (result) {
                    ia.getObject('div-' + key, reply.qInfo.qId);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Reload failed');
                }
            })
            .finally(function(){
                clearInterval(stop);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The above code results in the following error "Invalid visualization
The visualization was not found on the server: sheet"

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) To get the currently authenticated user, please use `getAuthenticatedUser`, example:

```
var global = qlik.getGlobal(config);
global.getAuthenticatedUser(function(reply){
    alert('User:'+reply.qReturn);
});
```

Reference: http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2017/Subsystems/APIs/Content/CapabilityAPIs/GlobalAPI/getAuthenticatedUser-method.htm

2) To get a list of apps, please use `getAppList`, example:

```
qlik.getAppList(function(list){
        var str = "";
        list.forEach(function(value) {
            str +=  value.qDocName + '('+ value.qDocId +') ';
        });
        alert(str);
    }
};
```

3) Here's the reference of all capabilities you can use: http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2017/Subsystems/APIs/Content/capability-apis-reference.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'll try this and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: For the user part that worked great. I've updated my question for you to check. Thank you

Comment: I've marked this as answered pretty much all of my question. If possible do you think you'd be able to look at the other error that is happening? Thank you for help to this point.